# How do I change the authorization domain using Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apps-marketplace

I have a Google Drive enabled application that I'm trying to get into the Google Apps Marketplace. It was rejected because:

> Your request begins : https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud?openid
>
> It should look more like :
>   https://www.google.com/a/DOMAIN_GOES_HERE/o8/ud

I've not been able to get an response from anyone at Google as to what this means.

We based our Drive operations on the [Java DrEdit example](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/java).

Is it possible, using the Google API Java Client Library, to use the second domain above, if so, how?

Also, even if it can be accessed, does it have access to the file permission settings I need in order to perform the various Drive operations?

Comment: Maybe you can find an answer to your first question on [this page](http://groups.google.com/group/google-apps-marketplace-api/tree/browse_frm/thread/9f5a4c3a8f8c0cc7/e05808486b306028?hide_quotes=no). I'm not sure if it's still valid, since it's a bit old (march 2011).

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately not. That's the wrong OAuth flavour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that it's not possible at this time. The variant of OAuth2 used with Google Drive does not permit forcing login to a particular domain.

The Google Apps Marketplace storekeepers should be allowing such applications to be accepted until a workaround is found.